# Java on macOS use system proxy automatically, how to disable it?

Tags: java, macos

I try set `export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='-Duser.language=en-US -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=false'`, but not work.

My network proxy setting:
[image]

I use manually downloaded JDK, not system builtin.

`java -XshowSettings:properties -version` output, we can see `http.proxyHost, socksProxyHost` in it:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.language=en-US -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=false
Property settings:
    http.proxyHost = 127.0.0.1
    http.proxyPort = 7891
    https.proxyHost = 127.0.0.1
    https.proxyPort = 7891
    java.class.path =
    java.class.version = 58.0
    java.net.useSystemProxies = false
    jdk.debug = release
    line.separator = \n
    os.arch = x86_64
    os.name = Mac OS X
    os.version = 10.15.5
    java.home = /Users/xxx/code/jdk/jdk-14.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
    path.separator = :
    socksProxyHost = 127.0.0.1
    socksProxyPort = 7891
    ......

java version "14.0.2" 2020-07-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.2+12-46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12-46, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Related question: [How does JVM automatic setting of OS X's System proxies work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847075/how-does-jvm-automatic-setting-of-os-xs-system-proxies-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simply use `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=` to unset the http proxy. You can do the same for https as well.

Comment: This does not work with the Apache HTTP Client:
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be empty
 at org.apache.http.util.Args.containsNoBlanks(Args.java:84) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14]
 at org.apache.http.HttpHost.<init>(HttpHost.java:80) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar!/:4.4.14]`

Comment: @stblassitude It looks like Apache HTTP Client takes empty string as a valid url, if you'd like to, you can submit a patch for it